# Add storeIds to widget loses information

Tags: magento

I want to add storeIds to a widget that already exists. This works but every time I save the widget, the widget loses its layout updates. So it doesn't know where it will be shown. How can I prevent that?

This is how I change the widget:

```
$widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load(44);
$storeIds = array('40', '6', '26');
$widget->setStoreIds($storeIds);
$widget->save();
```